# Killing Lara in Chapter 10

Tags: the-evil-within

I got stuck in chapter 10 where I need to kill Lara, what I did I ran all the time and only realized that I need to fight her when I got to the last room where one jumps down and there is no exit and you are forced to fight. I manage to burn her on all 3 corpses at the bottom and 2 pipe shots, I also throw 4 grenades on her while she's burning, I then use all the shotgun (8+10+2) and all the explosive bolts (3) and she still gets me. After replaying last part (and getting my head bashed ~30 times) I started to wonder why is this so hard.

**Does damage dealt to Lara before getting to last section of fight counts? Am I better of replaying the chapter and dealing her early damage rather then trying to beat the last section?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear problem was me being a dumbass all along!

I didn't need to kill Laura after all! What I had to do is to shoot at a 3rd switch after jumping down to open the furnace. After this fire in the corner goes off and lever to open second furnace becomes accessible. After pulling 2nd lever one needs to run around in the center of the room (with Lara chasing quite close) for a bit for fire that is blocking path to elevator to go off and path becomes clear.

Here's video:

Answer (score 0):

It would appear from looking through various discussions on this topic that it IS possible to kill her, however, if you hit her with burning damage, while she is still undergoing that effect she appears to be unaffected by other types of burning damage, maybe ANY damage (mixed reports in that regard).

When I played through I'm pretty sure I just ran!